# Biggest string, what is possible

Tags: python, algorithm

I had a list like

```
list=["apple","white","loop","edit","tow","took","know"]
```

and I want print, the longest string(the next words start with the previus last letter), without change the order of the words, like:

```
4
```

(apple, edit, took, know)
And I **can't** do (apple, edit, took, know,white), because than I need to change the order

Comment: What have you tried so far? See [ask] and [mcve] for details on how to ask a good questions. Being frank, this looks like a homework question. Not saying you won't get answers, but folks might be annoyed to answer it like this. If you showed some effort for it, you'd get more goodwill.

Comment: I have no clue what you are asking.

Comment: You need to [Find a simpler problem](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/21/find-a-simpler-problem/). Can you find *one* word that starts with the letter that the current word ends with? Can you measure the length of the chain that starts with the first word? Once you have those pieces, the solution should be much easier to grasp.

Comment: @timgeb `"apple"` ends with `'e'` and `"edit"` starts with `'e'`. What is the longest increasing subsequence of words linked like that? I think that the problem is clear enough, but still poorly written since no research.

Comment: @JohnColeman so IIUC, OP wants to find the longest possible chain of such words? edit: thanks for the explanation.

Comment: As a hint: as you iterate over the list, each word either starts a new chain or adds to 1 or more already existing chain of words. Only keep the longest chain which ends with that word, discarding the others. Build up all possible chains. When you are done -- which is longest?

Comment: This look like a great opportunity for recursion.

Comment: This problem intrigues me, so I whipped up a quick solution that runs in O(n^2) time. @JohnColeman's solution looks like it would run in O(n) but with O(n^2) space. I bet there's a solution that is linear in both but I'm trying to figure out an elegant way. (Edit: No, now that I think about it, John's solution can't run in linear time since it needs to iterate over all N words and over all K chains for each word. I wonder if a linear-time solution is possible, then...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution, running in O(n) time:

We keep track of the longest chain ending in each last letter we met. Each new word can either start a new chain, if its first letter isn't the end of any chain, or be added to the already found longest chain ending in that letter.

In turn, this new chain might be the new longest one ending in the last letter of the current word, or we can just discard it.

Finally, we just have to keep the longest of all found chains.

```
words = ["apple","white","loop","edit","tow","took","know"]

found_ends = {}
for word in words:
    if word[0] in found_ends:
        # This word can make a chain longer
        new_chain = found_ends[word[0]] + [word]
    else:
        # We start a new one
        new_chain = [word]
    # Is it the new longest chain for an end letter?
    if word[-1] not in found_ends or len(found_ends[word[-1]]) < len(new_chain):
        found_ends[word[-1]] = new_chain

print(max(found_ends.values(), key=len))
# ['apple', 'edit', 'took', 'know']
```

Note that I renamed your original list to `words`, as naming it `list` overshadows the Python builtin of the same name.

Answer (score 1):

```
list = ["apple","white","loop","edit","tow","took","know"] , answer = 4
```

- We can use dynamic programming approach to solve this.
- Here, we can adopt a bottom up approach, meaning we will go from last element to first element in the array.
- So, we start with `know` and we know that `know` has nothing ahead. So, we set it's value as `1`.
- Next we go with `took`. `took` has `know` to make a connection as you described. So, now for `took` the value is `2`(since 2 words in the chain).
- In the end, we will have an array of values for your list as `[4,4,1,3,1,2,1]`.
- Now, we just need to take max value among these values in the array and that is our answer.
- **Note that** in order to get the value of length of chain for a word, you need to get the **max** among **all possible chains too**.

**Pseudocode(since I am not a python enthusiast):**

```
chain_lengths = new int[words.length]
max_length = 0
for i = words.length - 1 to 0
   chain_lengths[i] = 1
   for  j = i + 1 to words.length
      if last_char(words[i]) == first_char(words[j]):
         chain_lengths[i] = max(chain_lengths[i],chain_lengths[j] + 1)
   max_length = max(chain_lengths[i],max_length)

print max_length
```

- Time Complexity : O(n^2)
- Space Complexity: O(n)
- Note that this would also ensure that the order of words is intact.

In actual Python:

```
words = ["apple","white","loop","edit","tow","took","know"]

chain_lengths = [None]*len(words)
max_length = 0
for i in range(len(words)-1,-1,-1):
   chain_lengths[i] = 1
   for j in range(i+1, len(words)):
      if words[i][-1] == words[j][0]:
         chain_lengths[i] = max(chain_lengths[i],chain_lengths[j] + 1)
   max_length = max(chain_lengths[i],max_length)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking about this question when I took a shower and I came up with a solution. I returned to this question to find that [Thierry Lathuille's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53249370/128397) already contains the same basic algorithm. But I think my implementation is slightly more optimized, and also slightly more Pythonic:

```
def longest_chain(words):
    chains = defaultdict(list)
    longest = []
    for word in reversed(words):
        first_char = word[0]
        last_char = word[-1]
        chain = chains[last_char] + [word]
        if len(chain) > len(chains[first_char]):
            chains[first_char] = chain
        if len(chain) > len(longest):
            longest = chain
    return list(reversed(longest))
```

This implementation actually returns the longest chain, although you could easily simplify it to only keep track of the length instead if that's all you need.

Congratulations on having successfully [nerd-sniped](https://xkcd.com/356/) me!

Comment: Even more pythonic would be to use a defaultdict.

Comment: @SilverSlash: I thought about `defaultdict` but I think `.get()` does everything I need here. But sure, I could change it to use `defaultdict(list)` instead.